# Google App Engine URL Routing with App.Yaml for Static resource and Script

Tags: google-app-engine, app.yaml, google-app-engine-php

I am busy migrating a app into the GAE. I used to utilize timthumb.php to resize images on demand from within a static img folder. From the same folder I used to serve static images aswel.

eg: example.com/img/image_name.jpg
    example.com/img/timbthumb.php?src=example.com/img/image_name.jpg&w=50&h=50

etc.

I am not using timbthump.php anymore, I have re-written it to serve images via CloudStorageTools.php api, and I do not want to go through all code to rewrite the image paths.

Now, on my local environment the google app engine is serving both versions of images, static and dynamic via timbthumb.php.

On the live environment GAE only serves static or dynamic, I cannot build URL handlers to serve both.

The timbthumb.php images are throwing a 404 error with both handlers.

My app.yaml

```
application: my-app
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /css
  static_dir: dir/css

 #timbthumb.php images
- url: /img/(.+\.php)$
  script: dir/img/timbthumb.php

#static images
- url: /img
  static_dir: dir/img

#all other php files
- url: /.*
  script: dir/index.php
```

My Question, how can I make GAE route static images via example.com/img/ and the timthumb.php script located at example.com/img/timbthumb.php in my app.yaml?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) you can't serve a script from a static directory:

> A static directory handler makes it easy to serve the entire contents
>   of a directory as static files. Each file is served using the MIME
>   type that corresponds with its filename extension unless overridden by
>   the directory's mime_type setting. All of the files in the given
>   directory are uploaded as static files, **and none of them can be run
>   as scripts**.

The fact that it appears to be running in the development server is just another reflection of the fact that the development server is just an approximation of GAE, but not really GAE.

If your image paths naming allows it you could use `static_files` routing rules instead of a `static_dir` one:

> A static file pattern handler associates a URL pattern with paths to
>   static files uploaded with the application. The URL pattern regular
>   expression can define regular expression groupings to be used in the
>   construction of the file path. **You can use this instead of
>   static_dir to map to specific files in a directory structure without
>   mapping the entire directory**.